# Retrieve number of pending AJAX requests with plain javascript

Tags: javascript, gwt, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I'm trying to retrieve the **number of pending** AJAX requests with plain javascript. This is to help make a module for Cheezy's page-object gem so that I can wait for AJAX requests in a GWT application. I can't switch to using JQuery, or any other javascript system as this is done in GWT.

I found this code which tells if the javascript is done, but I don't know much about javascript or how to adapt it to this system.

```
interValRef = 0;

interValRef = setInterval("checkState();",100)

function checkState(){
    if(document.readyState == 'complete'){
        clearInterval(interValRef);
        myFunc();
    }
}
```

Cheezy states that you need to have a single string that will return the number of pending AJAX requests. When that reaches 0 then it will be done waiting. So I guess if I could somehow just make this code output 1 for anything that isn't zero and then 0 when it's finally 0 I would be able to make this work.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it can be done with a simple

`"if (document.readyState == 'complete'){return 0} else {return 1}"`

in my case, though I guess that doesn't retrieve the number of requests, just if there are still requests. Oh well.

**Edit:** Hmm it seems as if this actually doesn't work, at least with GWT.